# Storing file in memory

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework, and I am wondering how could i store a file in memory using ionic after downloading the file

Definition of in memory here: The file in the location will be auto clear once the app is kill / exit.

I am looking on [ngCordova file plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) but could not find any location related that fits that purpose